# Redirect URL changing QUERY string parameter ? to & with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to change this url:

`http://blabla.nl/download/?url=https://www.bla.com/see?v=345345&type=download`

to this:

`http://blabla.nl/download/?url=https://www.bla.com/see&v=345345&type=download`

Using .htaccess
so the ? needs to change to an &.

at the moment i am not very succesfull fixing this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: i tried this, i am very new to this

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^see?v=/?$ 8/see&v= [NC,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(url=https://www\.youtube\.com/watch)\?(v=[A-Za-z0-9]+&type=downloa‌​d)
RewriteRule ^/?8/downloadff/?$ /8/downloadff/?%1&%2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I assume that the number `345345` is always a number an will be different all the times but the rest keeps the same.

Put this as `.htaccess` file on `http://example.nl/` or `http://example.nl/download/`

Comment: Yes with the numbers it works but in the real situation it will be somthing like this ALZHF5UqnU4 i geus  i will have to change this: [\d]?

Comment: yes sorry will do, Still cant get it to work this will be the link http://1.bvd2.nl/8/downloadff/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALZHF5UqnU4&type=download the quastion mark after the youtube.com/watch? i want to change to an & my htaccess looks like this now

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(url=https://www\.youtube\.com/watch)\?(v=[A-Za-z0-9]+&type=download)
RewriteRule ^/?8/downloadff/?$ /8/downloadff/?%1&%2 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^download/?url=https://www.bla.com/see&v=345345&type=download/?$ download/?url=https://www.bla.com/see?v=345345&type=download [NC,L]
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: did not work unfortunately, and is it possible that it doesn't matter what it says after the ?v= parameter but the ? will always be changed to an &

Comment: Yes, use a regex then

Comment: Where is your htaccess? In root directory?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489 for working with query strings.